# How can I download files over HTTPS with Perl?

Tags: perl, https

I want to download about 200 different HTML files over HTTPS and extract the title of the page from each file and put the titles into a text document.

How would I go about using Perl to download files using HTTPS? I searched Google, but I didn't find very much helpful information or examples.

Comment: Of the two answers, you chose to accept the one with 3 downvotes vs. the one with 7 upvotes?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to look for information on the downloading part is the [libwww-perl cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lwpcook.pod).

Here's some rudimentary sample code. It isn't necessarily the best way, but it's one that should work, assuming you have the LWP module (available from CPAN).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

while (my $site = <STDIN>)
{
    my $doc = get $site;
    if (defined($doc))
    {
        if ( $doc =~ m/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i )
        {
           print "$1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to add more bells and whistles, for unescaping text, handling error conditions, doing requests in parallel with multiple threads, faking user-agent as Mozilla etc :)

If you saved this as titlegrab.pl, and you had a list of sites in sites.list (one URL per line), you could use this with `$ cat sites.list | perl titlegrab.pl` to see all the titles.

Or.. redirect to some output file, e.g. `$ cat sites.list | perl titlegrab.pl > results.txt`

Comment: any ideas why I get this returned, when I use the HTTPS example from the link you gave me:

500 Can't locate object method "new" via package     "LWP::Protocol::https::Socket"

Comment: You probably need to manually install the Net::SSL module, which LWP depends on for https. Again, this should be easy to do via CPAN.

Comment: Don't read from STDIN - read from ARGV (or <> in this case). Also don't use regular expressions (and broken at that) to parse HTML - use an HTML parser.

Comment: I did say it was rudimentary! I ran this on an example list of URLs and it worked fine for me. I agree on the HTML parser, but in the interest of keeping things short for this simple task, the regex seemed adequate. Could you describe the brokenness in more detail?

Comment: What if the title tag and it's contents are not on a single line? Your regex fails. Use HTML::HeadParser instead. Also, you forgot to mention how to add HTTPS support: install Crypt::SSLeay before you run your code. And, you win the "Useless use of cat" award. :)

Comment: Points taken. Yes, this will only work for titles on the same line. You're right - it depends on Crypt::SSLeay, which in turn depends on Net::SSL. In my case, Net::SSL was the only missing part from a default installation. I can live with the overhead of 'cat'.

Comment: How is it "keeping things short" to write a lot of extra unnecessary code?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [HTML::HeadParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::HeadParser), part of the [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/) distribution. It will parse an HTML header for you to extract the `<title>` tag contents.

For fetching HTML content, there are a huge number of CPAN modules available. One such module is [LWP::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::Curl), which belongs to the [libwww-perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP) family. Search around on this site for [many discussions of fetching HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+perl) to learn more.

For downloading over HTTPS, take a look at the documentation under [libwww-perl](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.834/README.SSL). The current "standard" way to use SSL under libwww-perl is via [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Crypt::SSLeay).